# Stuck at .htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ $1.php [NC]
```

I want to remove .php extension and to add trailing slash.
But my code is just removing .php and also creating problems with some files such as i have a `file 2.php` in 'page' sub-directory and 'page' sub-directory is in 'blog' directory. So totally it forms `blog/page/2.php`.
So with `.htaccess` code, it must open with `blog/page/2`. But it's showing not found 404 error and get opens with `blog/page/2.php`.